# Finding "median" without averaging middle values

Tags: r

I want to extract an actual date from my dataset that is more or less in the middle.  `median()` works fine if I have an odd number of measurements.  However, if there are an even number of measurements, it *averages* the middle two, which produces a date that isn't in my dataset.

For the following example:

```
mydates <- as.Date(c("2016-02-18", "2016-03-30", "2016-05-31", "2016-08-19"))
median(mydates)
```

...what can I do to get R to return either "2016-03-30" or "2016-05-31", instead of "2016-4-30", which isn't in my original data set?

I don't care if it is the earlier or the latter date as long as it is consistent.

Comment: `sort(mydates)[floor((length(mydates)+1)/2)]` OR `sort(mydates)[ceiling((length(mydates)+1)/2)]`

Comment: or use the `%/%` operator to return a whole number `sort(mydates)[length(mydates) %/% 2]`

Comment: Or `max(mydates[mydates<=median(mydates)])`

Comment: Or `quantile(mydates,0.5,type=1)`.  See `?quantile` for other options.

Comment: So many great ways to approach this!  For readability and using in dplyr pipelines, quantile seems the way to go.  

I ended up using this in my dplyr pipe:   `summarise(beginning=as.Date(quantile(Date, probs=0.01)),
    middle=as.Date(quantile(Date, probs=0.5)),
    end=as.Date(quantile(Date, probs=0.99)) )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `quantile` function and specify the `type` as 1, 3 or 4.

```
> quantile(mydates, p = 0.5, type = 1)
         50% 
"2016-03-30" 
> quantile(mydates, p = 0.5, type = 3)
         50% 
"2016-03-30" 
> quantile(mydates, p = 0.5, type = 4)
         50% 
"2016-03-30"
```

See `?quantile` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Just trim a value from one end of your sorted data and take the `median` of that:

```
#later date
median(sort(mydates)[-1])
[1] "2016-05-31"
#earlier date
median(sort(mydates)[-length(mydates)])
[1] "2016-03-30"
```